# How do I fix Error 432 when loading a form in Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word .dot file which works in older versions of Word but fails with error 432 when run in Word 2013.

When I debug the code I have the line:

```
Load customerForm
```

And VBA shows the error:

`Run-time error '432': File name or class name not found during Automation operation`

The project "pennyscode" includes "Module1" which contains the function being debugged, "ThisDocument" and a form called "customerForm".

I have tried changing the name to "pennyscode.customerForm" but this doesn't make any difference.

This code is being called from a Sub function which is called from Document_New().

> Updates

I can place a breakpoint on the Load customerForm line and demonstrate that it is the line that is causing the problem. If at this point I mouse over the word "customerForm" VBA comes up with

```
customerForm = <Object variable or With block variable not set>
```

If I delete/skip the Load line then the next line is customerForm.Show and that produces the same error.

If I just open the .dotm file and then use Alt-F11 to open VBA, I can look at the code for selectCustomer, list properties/methods and customerForm appears in the list.

**Additional Note**
I believe that within the Load function it must be calling GetObject and it is this that is failing. It is as if VBA can't find the customerForm object even though it appears in the project.

I've posted the full code of the function being called from Document_New below.

```
Sub selectCustomer()
    Dim Doc As Document
    Set Doc = Application.ActiveDocument
    If Doc.CustomDocumentProperties.Item("Customer") = "Nothing" Then
        Load customerForm
        customerForm.Show
        Unload customerForm
        Doc.Fields.Update
        a$ = Doc.CustomDocumentProperties.Item("InvoiceNumber")
        a$ = customerForm.pathBox.Value + "\" + a$
        Doc.SaveAs (a$)
    End If
End Sub
```

I've also posted the full .dotm (Excel 2013) and .dot (previous excel) and some sample data (.xls) here:

[Dropbox/Public/Invoice 2015-16.dotm](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10974278/Invoice%202015-16.dotm)

[Dropbox/Public/Invoice 2015-16.dot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10974278/Invoice%202015-16.dot)

[Dropbox/Public/data.xls](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10974278/data.xls)

**Update**
I've not had much luck making progress on this question. Can anyone suggest an approach to investigating this? Or how I might improve the information on the question?

Comment: could you post all the code present in customerform

Comment: Do you really need to load it before it is displayed?

Comment: What happens if you use customerForm.Show - does that also result in an error? Or if have the form open in the VBA Editor and press F5? It's also important to note that if code your form is calling results in an error the debug might "jump back" to the Load statement, so this may not be the line of code causing the intial error.

Comment: Thanks for questions, I've edited the question to include answers and link to full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this, and I have a few learnings.

Firstly the debugger shows the error as occurring on the Load customerForm line, but this is actually not the case.

The customerForm has an _Initialize function which loads data into it before it is displayed. This function was failing with but the debugger stops on the wrong place.

I was able to debug this more effectively by putting a breakpoint on the start of the _Initialize sub and then stepping through the code.

Once I had discovered this I realized that the code was failing to find the XLSX file due to a wrong path, thus causing the run-time error.

Once I'd fixed up all the paths, I then hit a second error: runtime error '9' which is a subscript problem. This also reported on the Load customerForm line and was also due to a problem with the _Initialize function.

This was the true source of the problem, and demonstrated a functional change between Office 2013 and previous versions of Office.

My code was opening an XLSX file and attempting to read data from it:

```
Dim myXL As Object
Dim myWS As Object
Set myXL = GetObject("C:\Test\data.xlsx")

myXL.Application.Visible = True
myXL.Parent.Windows(1).Visible = True
Set myWS = myXL.Application.Worksheets("Customers")
```

The run-time error 9 was due to the index of the Windows property, as their were no windows. In previous versions of Office, there was a single window, with 2013 the array is empty.

After much messing about I tried adding this line:

```
myXL.Activate
```

before accessing the Windows() array. Once that was executed Windows(1) existed and the code worked as before.

Hope this can help someone else struggling with similar problems.